# Position of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ in class hierarchy for all integers $d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

For any real number $d,$ define 
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]: = \{a+b\sqrt{-d}: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$

It is well-known that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$ are ED but not fields, 
$$\mathbb{Z} \bigg[ \frac{1+\sqrt{19}}{2} \bigg]$$
is a PID but not ED, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-4}]$ are UFD but not PID.

What interests me is that different $d$ places $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ in different position in the [class hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

> Question: For all integer $d,$ do we know the position of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ is the class hierarchy?

Comment: But more concretely; for $d=-14$ the ring has been known to be a UFD since the (early) 19th century, but has been shown to be Euclidean only in 2004. Which suggests that the answer for general $d$ is a firm *no*.

Comment: @Servaes So you are suggesting that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ is an ED? How does that gives a negative answer to my question?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that determining where the ring is in the hierarchy is *very* difficult for most $d$.

Comment: @Servaes I see. However, I would be glad to see results for certain $d.$

Comment: To see if and how the unique factorization fails look at the ideals with  $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]/( I \cap \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]) \to O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})} / I $ not being an isomorphism